# Bing search api limit to certain sites

Tags: bing, bing-api

Can I define Bing search api only return result from subdomains from a site? For example, www.domain.com/dir/. This is something similar to what Google custom search does. But Google CSE has a hard limit on 10k/day. Is there an alternative search api available for this purpose?

Comment: You ask for a result from a subdomain, but the example you give is of a wildcard subdomain and a sub directory.  Can you clarify which one you want?

Comment: I just edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put this into the query field, like this:

`site:domain.com/dir/ whatIAmLookingFor`

The query field can contain anything the Bing Engine supports, despite the keyword being site, it apparently supports also URLs

You can read the Bing Search API docs [here](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!109&app=Word&authkey=!ACvyZ_MNtngQyCU).

Answer (score 3):

madmuffin is correct, but I'm expanding on his answer to show how multiple sites can be searched. You can use the [advanced search operator "site:"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795613.aspx) as part of your query "q" param.

**Single Site Example**

```
"heart disease" site:www.example.com
```

**Multiple Site Example**

```
"heart disease" (site:www.example1.com OR site:www.example2.com)
```